# Get IEnumerable<SelectListItem> from dbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have following database class

```
namespace Project.Web.Repository
{
    public class Database : DbContext
    {

        public Database(DbContextOptions<Database> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<SelectListItem> SelectListItem {get; set;}

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories()
        {
            var query = "SELECT Id as [Value], Name as [Text] FROM enum.Category";
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = SelectListItem.FromSql(query).ToList<SelectListItem>();
            return items;
        }

    }
}
```

But after call

```
_database.BrandCategories();
```

I am getting

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The entity type 'SelectListGroup' requires a primary key to be defined.'
```

What is the preferred way of getting select lists from database via EF Core ? Do i need to create POCO class for each table and after getting data convert the POCO class into SelectListItem collection ?

Comment: There are many things wrong with the code you have included. 1) Exception references a type ont shown in the code. 2) You have a DbSet for SelectListItem but do not include any mapping for this type to table 3) why would you use a raw query to get Categories and then also return a IEnumerable SelectListItem? You are mixing SoC, the DbContext should *not care* about select lists as that is something for the presentation layer to be concerned about. 4) You then have code to get `_database.BrandCategories` but do not include any code about this type or methods.

Comment: Thank you @Igor, i will take SoC into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only map to entity types via `FromSql`, i.e. types that belong to your context. However, once there, you can use LINQ's `Select` to map to something like `SelectListItem`:

```
var items = categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem 
    { 
        Value = x.Id, 
        Title = x.Name 
    }
);
```